# WebAPI does not respect Jwt token for authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have implemented all the steps [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and other tutorials at that site to issue and consume Jwt in my application using AngularJS and WebAPI. In my Startup.cs I am calling the following function to tell the app to consumer Jwt tokens when `AuthorizeAttribute` is present:

```
    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        string issuer = MyIssuer;
        string audienceId = MyAudienceID;
        X509Certificate2 cert = GetMyCertificate();

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, cert)
                }
            });
    }
```

When I run the application I can login just fine, generate the Jwt tokens just fine, consume them in angular and add them to the API requests, but I still get a 404. I must be missing something in the Jwt configuration so that it is not being validated, but I'm not getting any errors.

Just for the heck of it I tried implementing a customer `AuthorizeAttribute`, and put a breakpoint in the `IsAuthorized` method. You can see that the request contains the Bearer token, but `IsAuthorized` returns false, and the Principal is not set.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing? I'm so close here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably didn't have enough info in here to answer this properly, but it ended up being that I didn't submit my OWIN config statements in the right order. In Startup.cs I put `app.UseWebApi(config);` before the code that configured my authorization modules. Putting `app.UseWebApi(config);` at the end of the configuration code made it start working.

I posed this question better at the ASP.NET forums: http://forums.asp.net/p/2070482/5976299.aspx?p=True&t=635803483826595456